# Click on a hyperlink to go to another page

Tags: angular, typescript

In the `shareholder-information` page, I have a hyperlink.

```
<td class="text-center">
   <a [routerLink]="['portfolio/shareholder-information-details/'  ]">{{shareholder.isincode}}</a>
</td>
```

The complete code

```
<tr *ngFor="let shareholder of shareholdersLines">
   <td class="text-center">
      <a [routerLink]="['portfolio/shareholder-information-details/'  ]">{{shareholder.isincode}}</a>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center">{{shareholder.label}}</td>
   <td class="text-center"> {{shareholder.record_date }} </td>
   <td class="text-center"> {{shareholder.event_date  }} </td>
   <td class="text-center"> {{shareholder.event_type }} </td>
</tr>
```

When I click on the hyperlink, I should be redirected to the `shareholder-information-details` page.

My problem is that when I click on the hyperlink, nothing happens... I am not redirected to the `shareholder-information-details` page.

What's weird is that if I copy/paste the `shareholder-information-details` url into the address bar. I arrive on the `shareholder-information-details` page. So, the page exists.

**portfolio-routing**

```
{
    path: 'shareholder-information',
    component: ShareholderInformationComponent
}, {
    path: 'shareholder-information-details',
    component: ShareholderInformationDetailsComponent,
},
```

**shareholder-information.component.ts**

```
  constructor(
    private service: ShareholderInformationService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) 
    { }
```

**shareholder-information.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ShareholderInformationComponent],
    providers: [ShareholderInformationService],

    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        PipesModule,
        TranslocoModule
    ]
})
export class ShareholderInformationModule {}
```

I don't see my error?

Comment: Use routerLink without the brackets ````routerLink='portfolio/shareholder-information-details/'````

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the module this component is part of?

Comment: @Brandon Taylor, Sorry I edited my first message.

Comment: @Mustafa Yousef, I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you forget to add `ShareholderInformationDetailsComponent` to the `declarations` of your `ShareholderInformationModule` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the problem. I just had to add a `/` before `portfolio`. Here is the correct url `'/portfolio/shareholder-information-details/'` instead of `'portfolio/shareholder-information-details/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify the "/" on the routerlink it will append the content of routerlink to the current route.

if you are at domain.com/home

`<a [routerLink]="my-route">` will take you to domain.com/home/my-route

`<a [routerLink]="/my-route">` will take you to domain.com/my-route

Comment: Exactly, now it works `'/portfolio/shareholder-information-details/'`. Thank you so much.